# How can i get the Roomattributes Description which belongs to the Rooms SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have 3 Tables is my SQL Database:

```
First Table: Room: ID <pk>, Roomname
Second Table: RoomRelationsship: ID<pk>, Room_ID <fk>, Roomattributes_ID<fk>
Third Table: Roomattributes: ID<pk>, Attributename
```

How can i get the Roomattributes, which belongs to the Rooms. I need a SQL Query.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Room.ID, Room.Roomname, Roomattributes.Attributename 
FROM Room 
INNER JOIN RoomRelationsship ON RoomRelationsship.Room_ID = Room.ID
INNER JOIN Roomattributes ON RoomRelationsship.Roomattributes_ID = Roomattributes.ID
```